# Creating animated GIF files out of D3.js animations

Tags: animation, matplotlib, d3.js, gif, animated-gif

I am creating D3.js animations, like this: [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/WDCpq/8/)

Let's say I want to present my work here (or on a blog). About the best I can do is post a picture:

[image]

On the other hand, if I, let's say, use the Python library [Matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) for data visualization, I could produce an animated GIF file, and post it here:

[image]

[image]

I would like to programatically obtain similar animated GIF files out of my D3.js animations. How can I do this?

NOTE: I started working on getting events from `d3.transition()`, but so far I didn't have any luck.

Comment: [Tributary](http://tributary.io/) has a built-in function to grab animation as an animated GIF.  Even if you don't want to use their site, you could still check out their [source code](https://github.com/enjalot/tributary).

Comment: Thanks! That looks interesting. I'll try to use it on my animation and will get back to tell the results.

Comment: @AmeliaBR, amazing concept! But (as I understand) I can create gifs by clicking on D3.js animation, and each click produces individual gif, and after that all gifs are chained to create a larger animated gif. This will not work for my case, since I cant click 10 times a second, and also my clicking at any rate would produce a kind of not uniform gif sequence (and I want to display animations very precisely, just as D3.js does it - to show off the true power of d3.js and my  design skills). So, I guess I can't apply this to my particular case. But I will take a look at source, and thanks again.

Comment: I haven't looked at their code, but hopefully you can combine it with the transition progress event or with a timer function to get an even frame rate.  Come back and post an answer if you figure it out!

Comment: P.S.  Did you try holding the mouse down on tributary? -- that creates a stream of screen grabs, although I'm not sure how smooth the frame rate is.  Still haven't figured out how to actually save the result as a single animated GIF...

Comment: Yes, I was able to use "mouse down" feature to automatically get sequence of gifs. Still I have the hardest time getting usable animated gifs out of tributary. It looks frame rate is about 5 fps, and that number of frames and x y gif size are limited. It just couldn't serve my purpose. I need longish high quality anims. The idea is great though. See (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tributary/MS-ne9792ik) for introduction. Hopefully there will be some improvements.

Comment: I ran into two kinds of problems with tributary: 1. My samples didn't work out-of-the-box as inlets. Even samples from d3js.org; 2. Wasn't able to set options for gif capture. Probably I am missing something, but this should be more user-friendly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution uses a tool called LICEcap, a screen capture utility for Windows and Mac. Steps are following:

1. [Download LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) and install it. Now, if you start this program, it will have a rather unusual shape, just a thin frame, and everything inside the frame will be transparent:
   [image]
2. Go to the window with your D3.js animation and prepare everything so that you could start animation at some point. Let's say we want to record this example from d3js.org:
   [image]
3. Now start LICEcap and position it over the area you want to have in your animated GIF file:
   [image]
4. Make sure that you enter at least 20 [FPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate) in the bottom left edit box, otherwise the recording will be low quality. Press record. A dialog will first appear, and you choose here whether you want your GIF file to be in an infinite loop, or just repeated once, or any number of times. Also an interesting option is to add some visual clues for mouse clicks. Choose also filename, and press Save.
   [image]
5. Now you do whatever you have to do to trigger animations. I pressed buttons *Grouped* and *Stacked* several times. After I decided it's enough, I pressed *Stop*. The resulting file is:
   [image]

That's it!

Comment: Nice.  It's too easy to focus on the unique aspects of what you're working on, and forget to look at the big picture:  there's nothing D3-specific about wanting to create an animated screen grab!

Comment: For anyone looking for a similar UNIX command-line workflow: [You can  use `ffmpeg` for it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113695/gif-screencasting-the-unix-way).

Comment: thanks a lot. I never thought I'd find an answer to this so quickly.