# D3.js integration with Wikipedia

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, screenshot, wikipedia

Recently I have integrated [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) diagrams with my blog, see *[D3.js and Octopress](http://learnwrite.github.io/blog/2014/01/04/D3-and-Octopress/)*. How can I embed a [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) diagram inside a Wikipedia article or is there a workaround for that?

Comment: AFAIK D3 (and Javascript in general) can't be embedded in Wikipedia articles.

Answer (score 2):

Beside text, tables, sound, video, etc., you can add only pictures to Wikipedia. In fact, you add pictures to Wikimedia, and then use that picture in your Wikipedia article.

You can add a static picture of a D3.js visualization to Wikipedia, of course. You need a little of practice, there are multiple possibilities, and there are several nice tutorials about that within Wikipedia itself.

For animations, you can use animated GIF files, and a convenient procedure for getting animated GIF files out of your D3.js visualization is described in Stack Overflow question *[Creating animated GIF files out of D3.js animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864874)*.

Another option is video, but I think it would be most likely an overkill for your purpose.

As far as complete D3.js-powered web applications are concerned - no, it's not possible to integrate that in any way in a Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

You can save SVG file from SVG generated by D3.js.